# R: Match Data Frame Elements with Vector Elements

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working with a large data frame of patient data containing ICD codes, and I want to see if any codes in the list match those from a predefined list. I'd prefer the results of the test to output into my dataframe as a new column. Ideally I'd like to go from something like this:

```
dx1   dx2   dx3  ...  dx15
4210  3359  2214      8178
V0832 12218 7423      2294
6463  3438  3243      1129
```

To something like this:

```
dx1   dx2   dx3  ...  dx15  ENDO
4210  3359  4211      8178  TRUE
V0832 12218 7423      2294  TRUE
6463  3438  E3243      1129  FALSE
```

I created a vector with my codes of interest:

```
ICD9EndoCodes <-c("4210","4211","4219","4249","421","11281")
```

But haven't been able to figure out how to perform the logical test on element of my data frame and output a single column. The closest I've come is:

```
x <-ifelse(df_04_13[,4:18] == "4210", TRUE, FALSE)
```

...which creates a matrix "x" with the true and false correctly assigned for each position in the matrix. But when I've taken a stab at generalizing it...

```
x <- for(i in 1:length(ICD9EndoCodes)) 
     ifelse(df_04_13[,4:18] == ICD9EndoCodes[i], TRUE, FALSE)
```

I get "null". I feel like I'm overlooking an obvious, straightforward way to go about this, but my unfamiliarity with the environment has left me struggling.

Comment: It worked beautifully using the reduce() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of one way without reshaping your data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="id dx1   dx2   dx3  dx15
1 4210  3359  2214  8178
2 V0832 12218 7423  2294
3 6463  3438  3243  1129", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Loop over each column and check if any values matches an ICD code in your list. Then collapse via `Reduce()` each of these column indicators using the `|` function which represents an "OR", to get your row-level indicator:

```
Reduce(`|`, lapply(dat[2:5], `%in%`, ICD9EndoCodes))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Though I suspect this type of data is more easily worked with in a "long" form in the long run (pun intended). It's also most likely a hugely more efficient and flexible way to store ICD codes if most patients only have 1 or 2 diagnoses instead of everyone getting a uniform 15 recorded.

Flag / aggregate / merge. This logic will work regardless of whether you have 1 `dxN` column, 15 or 115, as they are now all collapsed to a single column. E.g.:

```
long <- cbind(dat[1], stack(dat[-1]))

# flag
long$icdhit <- long$values %in% ICD9EndoCodes

# aggregate
icdagg <- aggregate(icdhit ~ id, data=long, FUN=any)
#  id icdhit
#1  1   TRUE
#2  2  FALSE
#3  3  FALSE

# merge
merge(dat, icdagg, by="id", all.x=TRUE)
#  id   dx1   dx2  dx3 dx15 icdhit
#1  1  4210  3359 2214 8178   TRUE
#2  2 V0832 12218 7423 2294  FALSE
#3  3  6463  3438 3243 1129  FALSE
```

Comment: I ended up implementing the Flag/Aggregate/Merge workflow as a function so I could test several different ICD code sets:

Comment: @BrianErly - that's the big benefit of the method. It's a consistent structure with 1 column of values that is easily turned into a repeatable function.

Answer (score 1):

The [icd](https://jackwasey.github.io/icd/) package, of which I'm an author, does exactly this:

`library(icd)
pts <- data.frame(id = c("pt1", "pt2"), 
  dx1 = c("410", "V10"), 
  dx2 = c("4219", "11281"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ICD9EndoCodes <-c("4210","4211","4219","4249","421","11281")
res <- icd::comorbid(pts, map = list(endo = ICD9EndoCodes))
cbind(pts, res)`


     `id dx1   dx2 endo
pt1 pt1 410  4219 TRUE
pt2 pt2 V10 11281 TRUE`

There are comorbidity calculation examples in the [introduction](https://jackwasey.github.io/icd/articles/introduction.html) and other documentation using a custom map (like this example) and the standard mappings from Elixhauser, Quan, Charlson, etc..

Comment: Nice package. Bookmarked and will share this one with others for sure. I wonder about the legalities of adapting the package to cope with the ICD10-AM?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using `tidyverse`:

```
df %>%
 mutate_all(funs(ifelse(. %in% ICD9EndoCodes, 1, 0))) %>% #Comparing the values in df with the values in the vector and assigning 1 when there is a match
 mutate(ENDO = ifelse(rowSums(.) >= 1, TRUE, FALSE)) %>% #Counting the number of matches
 select(ENDO) %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 left_join(df %>%
            rowid_to_column(), by = c("rowid" = "rowid")) %>% #Merging the results with the original df
 select(-rowid)

   ENDO   dx1   dx2  dx3 dx15
1  TRUE  4210  4211 2214 8178
2 FALSE V0832 12218 7423 2294
3 FALSE  6463  3438 3243 1129
```

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "dx1   dx2   dx3 dx15
4210  4211  2214      8178
           V0832 12218 7423      2294
           6463  3438  3243      1129", header = TRUE)

ICD9EndoCodes = c("4210","4211","4219","4249","421","11281")
```